# Windows Update Won't Open On Win2k8 R2

Tags: windows, windows-update

When I try and open the Windows Update control panel it either never displays, or displays a partially rendered Windows Update window and never seems to "unfreeze".

I've tried cycling the Windows Update service (which seems to stall during the Stop process until I kill it using Task Manager), but that doesn't seem to help.

I've also rebooted several times.

This started happening after installing today's (4/12/2011) patches. I hadn't installed patches in several months, so it could have been one of many different patches that caused it.

Short of uninstalling the patches I just installed, are there any other debugging tips?

Comment: Is there anything in the event logs?

Comment: Another suggestion would be to download and apply SP1.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would try and back the patches out.  You say you don't want to do this so much so you might want to download and run MBSA, [Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc184923).  This tool can tell you if you have partially installed patches, misconfiguration, and also let you download patches via direct links in the application.  I have used it a few times to get stuborn machines back on track.